# Error installing scrapy 0.22 (on Ubuntu 12.04): 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy

When trying to install Scrapy from the command line using pip

`sudo pip install scrapy`
I get the following error:

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Looking a few lines up in the error output, I see that the error occurs while trying to install the 'cryptography' package which seems to be a dependency of pyOpenSSL

I tried installing pyOpenSSL on its own and it gives the same error.
Reading through the error output, I find that the likely cause of this error is a missing file:

`ffi.h: No such file or directory`

How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with

`sudo apt-get install libffi libffi-dev`

Comment: Installing libffi-dev worked (libffi was not found on the repo). Thanks!