# Error while installing scrapy vol 2.0

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, web-hosting

I have same problem [Error while installing scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917657/error-while-installing-scrapy). There is advice how to solve it, but i want to deploy scrapy on web hosting. I have no permisssions to use `sudo apt-get install  libffi-dev`. I'm using myenv.

Is there any other ways to solve this problem?

P.S.: I have only 11 rep points so i cant comment...

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask your hosting provider to install the package for you. This is the easy way.
2. The hard way:

   - Get the libffi source from the official site https://sourceware.org/libffi/
   - Unpack the source
   - Pass `--global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/path/to/unpacked/libffi/source"` to pip install
     With some luck (as the headers from source and the library installed on the web host's server may be different versions), this will work.